# URL naming not working in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

When I go to /blog/tag/1 to see the first existing tag item, which renders response to tag.html, I get an exception:  "Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''add-node'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

I have something like this in my **URLs.py:**

```
url(r'^blog/add_node/$', 'Alpha.Gamma.views.add_node', name='add-node'),
```

**The Views.py:**

```
def add_node(request):
    tag = Tag.objects.all()
    action = reverse("add-node-proc")
    title = "Submit Article"

    return render_to_response("blog/add_node.html", add_csrf(request, action=action, title=title, tags=tag, button="Submit Article"))
```

The Template of **tag.html** has:

```
<a id="new_node" class="buttont" href="{% url 'add-node' %}">Add new blog post</a>
<br />
<br />
```

The error I am getting:

NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''add-node'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

It highlights the line I put for tag.html above.

add_node.html is a simple form template. What am I doing wrong, the documentation says I'm doing everything right.

If I change on the template: "url 'add-node'" to "url Alpha.Gamma.views.add_node", everything works all of a sudden---why??? I don't understand this django url dispatcher.

Yes I have restarted the apache several times.

Comment: Try to drop quotation marks around add-node in template and see if it works.

Comment: It passes. But the documentation misled me and told me to use {% url 'arch-summary' 1945 %}
{% url 'full-archive' 2007 %} https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I encourage you to send a bug report :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the url tag, note that you don't need quotes around the url name:

`{% url add-node %}`

not

`{% url 'add-node' %}`

Comment: Or, if you're using Django 1.3 or Django 1.4, an alternative is to leave the quotes, and add `{% load url from future %}` to your template. See the section on forwards compatibility in the [url tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: This is something I thought of, but I said to myself, "not possible,  because the documentation has: " {% url 'arch-summary' 1945 %}
{% url 'full-archive' 2007 %}  as an example. Why put in quotes if the correct way is to not put in quotes??? Did Django mess up documentation?